# With Firebase Unity SDK, why is 'newUser.uid' and 'auth.CurrentUser.UserId' the email and not UID?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

Im using Firebase with Unity and when trying to create a database entry for a recently signed up user, I would like to store by the created UID.

However:

```
DatabaseManager.sharedInstance.CreateNewPlayer (player, auth.CurrentUser.UserId);
```

and

```
DatabaseManager.sharedInstance.CreateNewPlayer (player, newPlayer.UserId);
```

In both cases "UserId" is the email, rather than the UID created for each new user.

Some relevant code from around my project to give an idea of how I'm going about it:

```
FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl (<my app url>);
auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
```